# Smoothest way to render large matrices to canvas element

Tags: html, performance, matrix, html5-canvas

I have created a dot matrix slider on a `canvas` element (much like the sort you get in the stock exchange).  Currently I have each letter laid out as an individual matrix and then, through a succession of loops I have these letter converted into one large matrix.

I then go through and draw this matrix column by column up to a maximum amount of columns.  The matrix then gets redrawn every X milliseconds, offsetting the viewable area of the matrix by one each iteration until it eventually loops.  The large matrix doesn't get redrawn every time.

My issue is that the animation doesn't seem smooth at lower redraw intervals - it jumps about.  I've checked the frame rate and it seems fine but occasionally it jumps and I can't work out why!

The function with the settings is right at the bottom of the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C3Z7x/).

```
dotMatrix({
    animationDelay: 1000,
    canvasSelector: '#dot-matrix',
    dotRadius: 2,
    loop: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some steps you could do:

- Prerender each char to an off-screen canvas in a solid color on transparent background. This canvas will be used as a sprite-sheet later. Drawing a rounded rectangle is a relative expensive operation especially when you need x number of it per char.
- Set up a gradient for the colors and store that too in an off-screen canvas (by now we can see memory-caching is coming to the rescue..).
- Every time you update use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of setInterval. The latter is not able to synchronize to monitor update. Scroll delay can be calculated using the number of frames elapsed as well as the time since last update (see [rAF doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) for details).
- For each update clear, then "blit" the letter from the sprite-sheet canvas to main canvas. When all are blitted change composite mode to `source-atop` and blit the gradient canvas on top, and reset composite mode to `source-over` (don't use save/restore - they are expensive).

In the last step you could also use composite mode `copy` instead of clearing canvas and using source-over, as that will remove any previous existing pixels for the area you draw to.

Hope this gives you some inputs to improve the performance.